# How to display album art for MP3?

Tags: android

I tried 2 days full and even after that I really can't display my MP3 file's album art. The MP3 file is located in `R.raw.t`. Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: So you have the mp3 file in R.raw.t. Where is the album cover image you want to display?

Answer (score 0):

Found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1954434/cover-art-on-android) older Topic.

It seams, that the given link to the Android Music Player-App isn't available anymore. But, a Mirror on GitHub can be found [here](https://github.com/android/platform_packages_apps_music).

If we now take a look on the ['MusicUtils'-class](https://github.com/android/platform_packages_apps_music/blob/master/src/com/android/music/MusicUtils.java), we see that the Album ID comes from an Object called 'sService', which is a 'IMediaPlaybackService'-Instance. This is an AIDL-File, so we look at the implementation in the ['MediaPlaybackService'-Class](https://github.com/android/platform_packages_apps_music/blob/master/src/com/android/music/MediaPlaybackService.java).

So this is the 'getAlbumID()'-method we find:

```
public long getAlbumId() {
    synchronized (this) {
        if (mCursor == null) {
            return -1;
        }
        return mCursor.getLong(mCursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Audio.Media.ALBUM_ID));
    }
}
```

'MediaStore' is a standard Android Content-Provider, which is documented [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/MediaStore.html).

Comment: Anything on what is not working, what are our problems and do you get any errors might help us solving this problem.

Comment: Provide some Error code or what is happening, I can't help you with that less informations.