# Can't use Media.ALBUM_ART

Tags: android

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [cover art on android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1954434/cover-art-on-android)

I'm having a weird problem with Android Content Resolver. I'm trying to do a simple query for the Album Art of a music, but it's throwing an exception.

Here is the code:

```
Cursor cursor = context.getContentResolver().query(
    MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, 
    new String[] { MediaStore.Audio.Media.ALBUM_ART }, 
    null, 
    null,
    null);
```

And I'm getting the following exception:

05-16 09:27:38.319: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3860): Caused by: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such column: album_art: , while compiling: SELECT album_art FROM audio

But if audio table doesn't have the column album_art, why there is MediaStore.Audio.Media.ALBUM_ART?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had the same problem. The solution is at this SO question: [cover art on android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1954434/cover-art-on-android)