# Extract album cover from mp3 file in android

Tags: android, mp3

Hello Everyone , 
        In my media player i need to display the album cover(i dont know how it pronounced actually..I hope right) of the song. I knew for that i have to extract the image from the song itself but how? m wondering. So any help, if possible with some sorts of code. Thanks.

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1954434/cover-art-on-android

Answer (score 22):

for api 10 and above

```
android.media.MediaMetadataRetriever mmr = new MediaMetadataRetriever();
        mmr.setDataSource(songsList.get(songIndex).get("songPath"));

        byte [] data = mmr.getEmbeddedPicture();
               //coverart is an Imageview object

        // convert the byte array to a bitmap
        if(data != null)
        {
            Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(data, 0, data.length);
            coverart.setImageBitmap(bitmap); //associated cover art in bitmap
        }
        else
        {
            coverart.setImageResource(R.drawable.fallback_cover); //any default cover resourse folder
        }

            coverart.setAdjustViewBounds(true);
            coverart.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(500, 500));
```

Answer (score 4):

Try [FFmpegMediaMetadataRetriever](https://github.com/wseemann/FFmpegMediaMetadataRetriever):

```
FFmpegMediaMetadataRetriever retriever = new FFmpegMediaMetadataRetriever();
retriever.setDataSource(uri);
byte [] data = retriever.getEmbeddedPicture();

// convert the byte array to a bitmap
Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(data, 0, data.length);
// do something with the image ...
// mImageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);

retriever.release();
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try with Picasso by using album_id. it is open source & less memory cache.

Dependency:

```
implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.71828'
```

Code:

```
String albumId = songObject.getAlbum_id();

final Uri albumUri = Uri.parse("content://media/external/audio/albumart");

Uri uri = ContentUris.withAppendedId(albumUri, Long.parseLong(albumId));

    Picasso.get().load(uri)
            .fit()
            .centerCrop()
            .error(R.drawable.img_album)
            .into(holder.imgAlbumSongObject);
```

This is very late. but, may help someone.

Answer (score -2):

```
 MediaMetadataRetriever mmr = new MediaMetadataRetriever();
 mmr.setDataSource(filePath);

String albumName = mmr.extractMetadata(MediaMetadataRetriever.METADATA_KEY_ALBUM));
```

Note this will work only at api level 10 or above

Comment: you should comment the code better, at least type in `Try this:`, better place a link to MediaMetaDataRetriever reference...

Comment: this does not answer the question of how to extract album artwork (image)

Comment: This is retrieving the album name (if set), not the album cover image.