# Android retrieve cover art of song while playing in MediaPlayer

Tags: android

I was wondering if there is a way how can I get the cover photo of a song while playing it on `MediaPlayer`. Every song is directly streamed from the internet but I know that `MediaPlayer` is temporally saving it on `Device`.

I know about `MediaMetadataRetriever` but I don't think it will work in my case.

Answer (score 2):

MediaMetadataRetriever's [getEmbeddedPicture](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaMetadataRetriever.html#getEmbeddedPicture()) may be of help for you. Refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21549403/1552136) .
Also, getArtwork() method in the [code](https://github.com/android/platform_packages_apps_music/blob/master/src/com/android/music/MusicUtils.java#L986) of android platform music player maybe of some help.

Use the below snippet to set the data source for your MediaMetadataRetrieverObject. where link is the url of your file. This is hould be done before calling getArtwork().

```
     if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 14)
        MediaMetadataRetrieverObject.setDataSource(link, new HashMap<String, String>());
     else
        MediaMetadataRetrieverObject.setDataSource(link);
```

Comment: Is there a way to get the path of downloaded song from mediaPlayer?