# Fresco obtaining embedded cover art

Tags: java, android, image, pipeline, fresco

The Android **fresco** image loading library provides a variety of components to customize image loading from several sources. In my situation, I want to retrieve the embedded cover art of an audio/mp3 file (*not* the album art which can be accessed using an uri). This can be achieved using the [Android MediaMetadataRetriever](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21549403/3162424) or some custom library like [FFmpegMediaMetadataRetriever](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20208074/3162424).

The problem is, that the API always requires a *PATH* and returns an *array of bytes*. This makes it hard integrate into the stream-based fresco pipeline.

Ideally, I would like to implement this similar to how [Glide allows it](https://github.com/bumptech/glide/issues/699#issuecomment-149598922). Aka some very low-level function which obtains the bytes and simply wraps them in a stream. Afaik, we can use custom [*Decoders*](https://github.com/facebook/fresco/tree/dabece10e6c3f8fc326adee2ed9bba3a723ca164/samples/showcase/src/main/java/com/facebook/fresco/samples/showcase/imageformat), but not *Producers*. The data has already been loaded at Decoder stage. I have no idea at which layer this should happen and if it's possible.

Glide code for reference:

```
@Override public InputStream loadData(Priority priority) throws Exception {
    MediaMetadataRetriever retriever = new MediaMetadataRetriever();
    try {
        retriever.setDataSource(model.path);
        byte[] picture = retriever.getEmbeddedPicture();
        if (picture != null) {
            return new ByteArrayInputStream(picture);
        } else {
            return fallback(model.path);
        }
    } finally {
        retriever.release();
    }
}
```

The result will be loaded into a SimpleDraweeView. Alternatively, I'm open to any solution which will allow me to asynchronously load embedded cover art into a SimpleDraweeView using fresco.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've [forked fresco and added my own Producer](https://github.com/pablode/fresco/commit/655f5ab8b83971ba048df19c1c176d1c76a435bf) which is able to extract the embedded pictures of audio files similar to the Glide solution in the provided snippet. This LocalAudioThumbnailProducer applies to content with the `audio/` MimeType. I've also written a small [sample app](https://github.com/pablode/fresco/commit/d312dfa89a7ca16e3e16d68abd96bc01be93b648) to showcase the usage.

Please note that this raises the current minimum SDK version from 9 to 10.