# How get album cover? ALBUM_ART column index is -1

Tags: android, cursor, media-player, mediastore, albumart

I want cover album for songs in my phone but I get colum index -1

```
        int imageColumn = musicCursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.AlbumColumns.ALBUM_ART);
```

This is the full code:

```
// Retrieve song info from device
public void getSongList() {
    String selection = MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_MUSIC + " != 0";

    // Query external audio
    ContentResolver musicResolver = getActivity().getContentResolver();
    Uri musicUri = android.provider.MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
    Cursor musicCursor = musicResolver.query(musicUri, null, selection, null, null);

    // Iterate over results if valid
    if (musicCursor != null && musicCursor.moveToFirst()) {
        // Get columns
        int titleColumn = musicCursor.getColumnIndex
                (android.provider.MediaStore.Audio.Media.TITLE);
        int idColumn = musicCursor.getColumnIndex
                (android.provider.MediaStore.Audio.Media._ID);
        int artistColumn = musicCursor.getColumnIndex
                (android.provider.MediaStore.Audio.Media.ARTIST);
        int durationColumn = musicCursor.getColumnIndex
                (MediaStore.Audio.Media.DURATION);

        int imageColumn = musicCursor.getColumnIndex
                (MediaStore.Audio.AlbumColumns.ALBUM_ART);
        // ****** HERE I HAVE -1, the same is with MediaStore.Audio.Albums.ALBUM_ART ******


        // Add songs to list
        do {
            long thisId = musicCursor.getLong(idColumn);
            String thisTitle = musicCursor.getString(titleColumn);
            String thisArtist = musicCursor.getString(artistColumn);
            long thisDuration = musicCursor.getLong(durationColumn);

            String thisPathAlbumImage =  musicCursor.getString(imageColumn); 
            // ****** HERE MY APP CRASH FOR -1 INDEX ******

            arrayOfSongs.add(new Song(thisId, thisTitle, thisArtist, thisDuration, thisPathAlbumImage));

            Log.d(LOG_TAG, "New song added: " + thisTitle);
        }
        while (musicCursor.moveToNext());
    }
}
```

Why I get -1? I want each album cover to set them in a ListView with song title, artist name and duration.

Comment: use `DatabaseUtils.dumpCursor(musicCursor)` to see your `Cursor`

Answer (score 1):

You should use `Uri.parse("content://media/external/audio/albumart");` to query the albumart. You can have more information at  [this StackOverflow post.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13678457/4507959)

Answer (score 1):

The query that you are using does not return the column `MediaStore.Audio.AlbumColumns.ALBUM_ART`. You now have certain options.

1. You can use the answer provided and linked by @nawako. But as this 
   [tweet](https://twitter.com/ianhlake/status/658380560910303232) from Ian Lake reminds us, it is not explicitly part of the official SDK could be changed or modified.
2. You can use a query that returns the column. Using `MediaStore.Audio.Albums.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_TYPE` will retrieve a list of albums, as well as include `MediaStore.Audio.AlbumColumns.ALBUM_ART`. Please note, this option does not load any music, you will need a separate query for that.
3. You can retrieve the cover from the using using the method in this 
   [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15314617/get-cover-picture-by-song/16972099#16972099). This does not involve any modification of your current query.

Here is some sample code implementing option 2.

```
Bitmap art;
String path;
Uri artUri;
Uri musicUri = android.provider.MediaStore.Audio.Albums.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;

.
.
.

path = musicCursor.getString(imageColumn);

if (path != null) {
    artUri = Uri.fromFile(new File(path));

    try {
         coverArt = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(musicResolver, artUri);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // For some reason we have no album art. Assign a default cover?
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply... the best way is the number 2? Any examples? Thanks again :)

Comment: if imageColumn is "imageColumn = musicCursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.AlbumColumns.ALBUM_ART);" I always get -1 index :(

Comment: I try with "int imageColumn2 = musicCursor2.getColumnIndex (MediaStore.Audio.Albums.ALBUM_ART);", index is 9 but it always crash: "CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index -1 requested, with a size of 10"... but wait, it's better if i can extrat cover album in each song, i don't want all album because then I have to connect each song with each cover song, I have only a song list and I want cover album for each song...