# Fetch albums with their artist names according to Play Music

Tags: android, android-cursor, mediastore

I am trying to fetch all the albums from the device and displaying it. And it works fine. But I observed that the Artist for Album is showing differently in Play music . Is there any other way to get the artist other than the below code?

```
Uri uri = MediaStore.Audio.Albums.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
String[] cols = new String[] {
            MediaStore.Audio.Albums._ID,
            MediaStore.Audio.Albums.ARTIST,
            MediaStore.Audio.Albums.ALBUM,
            MediaStore.Audio.Albums.ALBUM_ART
    };
 Cursor cursor = MusicUtils.query(this, uri,
                    cols, null, null, MediaStore.Audio.Albums.DEFAULT_SORT_ORDER);

mArtistIdx = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Audio.Albums.ARTIST);
String artistName = cursor.getString(mArtistIdx);
```

Comment: The links in this answer might help: http://stackoverflow.com/a/16707182/450534.

Comment: refer : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13678391/get-album-art-with-album-name-android

Comment: @IceMAN I am not looking for any third party API. Looking for way to get it through mediastore itself.

Comment: @Logic your link is not relevant to my question.