# Listing images embedded with song files into the sub item of the listview

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-music-player

I have listed all the songs into a `listview` and played them very well but the problem is i want to set the images and album name as the sub item of that `ListView`

I have used `cursor = managedquery()` method to list song and play but please tell me how can i fetch the embedded image with song files and set them as the sub item of the list view like  any other music player app

Comment: where is ur code?

Comment: refer http://stackoverflow.com/a/13678457/6478047  and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17573972/how-can-i-display-album-art-using-mediastore-audio-albums-album-art