# Picasso not working to load album art

Tags: android, picasso, albumart

```
public void getAlbumArt(){
    final Uri albumArtUri = MediaStore.Audio.Albums.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;

    Cursor albumCursor = getContentResolver().query(albumArtUri, null, null, null, null);

    if (albumCursor != null && albumCursor.moveToFirst()){
        int album_Art = albumCursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Audio.Albums.ALBUM_ART);
        do {
            String albumArt = albumCursor.getString(album_Art);
            QuerySongs querySongs = new QuerySongs(null, null, null, null, null, albumArt);
            songList.add(querySongs);
        }while(albumCursor.moveToNext());
        albumCursor.close();
    }
}
```

**Adapter class**

```
public void onBindViewHolder(SongHolder holder, final int position) {
    //holder.tvIndex.setText(String.format(Locale.US, "%d", position));
    holder.tvSongTitle.setText(songList.get(position).getTitle());
    holder.tvArtistName.setText(songList.get(position).getArtist());

    Picasso.with(context)
            .load(Uri.parse("file://"+songList.get(position).getAlbumart()))
            .error(R.drawable.no_album)
            .into(holder.albumIv);

}
```

I have a problem with getting the album art from songs on the sd-card, what is the easiest way to get the album art, and display it in an imageview?
I have no clue what i'm doing wrong, i looked at other posts on this forum, but with no avail, still haven't found out how to do it correctly.

Thanks,

**EDIT**

```
public void getAlbumArt(){
    final Uri albumArtUri = MediaStore.Audio.Albums.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;

    Cursor albumCursor = getContentResolver().query(albumArtUri, null, null, null, null);

    if (albumCursor != null && albumCursor.moveToFirst()){
        int albumart_Column = albumCursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Audio.Albums.ALBUM_ART);

        do {
            String albumArt = albumCursor.getString(albumart_Column);
            QuerySongs querySongs = new QuerySongs(null, null, null, null, null, albumArt);
            songList.add(querySongs);
        }while(albumCursor.moveToNext());
        albumCursor.close();
    }
    albumIv = findViewById(R.id.albumIv);
    Picasso.with(context)
            .load(albumArtUri)
            .error(R.drawable.no_album)
            .into(albumIv);
}
```

**Song Constructor**

```
package com.vince_mp3player.mp3player;

/**
* Created by Vincent on 12/11/2017.
*/

public class QuerySongs {
long id;
long albumid;
String data;
String title;
String artist;
String albumart;



   public QuerySongs(Long songId, Long albumId, String songData,  String 
   songName, String songArtist, String albumArt){
    this.id = songId;
    this.albumid = albumId;
    this.data = songData;
    this.title = songName;
    this.artist = songArtist;
    this.albumart = albumArt;

}

public Long getId(){
    return id;
}

public long getAlbumid() { return albumid; }

public String getData(){
    return data;
}


public String getTitle() {
    return title;
}


public String getArtist() {
    return artist;
}

public String getAlbumart() { return albumart; }
```

}

**Display Song Class**

```
public void getAlbumArt(){
    final Uri albumArtUri = MediaStore.Audio.Albums.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;

    Cursor albumCursor = getContentResolver().query(albumArtUri, null, null, null, null);

    if (albumCursor != null && albumCursor.moveToFirst()){
        int albumart_Column = albumCursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Audio.Albums.ALBUM_ART);

        do {
            Uri albumArt = Uri.parse(albumCursor.getString(albumart_Column));

            QuerySongs querySongs = new QuerySongs(null, null, null, null, null, albumArt);
            songList.add(querySongs);
        }while(albumCursor.moveToNext());
        albumCursor.close();
    }
}
```

**SongAdapter**

```
 @Override
public void onBindViewHolder(SongHolder holder, final int position) {
    //holder.tvIndex.setText(String.format(Locale.US, "%d", position));

    holder.tvSongTitle.setText(songList.get(position).getTitle());
    holder.tvArtistName.setText(songList.get(position).getArtist());

    Picasso.with(context)
            .load(Uri.parse(songList.get(songIndex).getAlbumart()))
            .error(R.drawable.no_album)
            .into(holder.albumIv);

}
```

**EDIT 2**

```
 public void getSongs() {
    final Uri songUri = MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;

    String selection = MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_MUSIC + "!=0";
    Cursor myCursor = getContentResolver().query(songUri, null, selection, null, null);


    if (myCursor != null && myCursor.moveToFirst()) {
        int id_Column = myCursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Audio.Media._ID);
        int albumId_Column = myCursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Audio.Media.ALBUM_ID);
        int data_Column = myCursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Audio.Media.DATA);
        int title_Column = myCursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Audio.Media.TITLE);
        int artist_Column = myCursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Audio.Media.ARTIST);
        int album_Column = myCursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Audio.Media.ALBUM);

        do {

            Long songId = myCursor.getLong(id_Column);
            Long albumId = myCursor.getLong(albumId_Column);
            String songData = myCursor.getString(data_Column);
            String songName = myCursor.getString(title_Column);
            String songArtist = myCursor.getString(artist_Column);
            String songAlbum = myCursor.getString(album_Column);

            Uri sArtworkUri = Uri.parse("content://media/external/audio/albumart");
            Uri albumArtUri = ContentUris.withAppendedId(sArtworkUri, albumId);

            Bitmap bitmap = null;

            try {
                bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(context.getContentResolver(), albumArtUri);
                bitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmap, 30, 30, true);
            }catch (FileNotFoundException exception ){
                exception.printStackTrace();
                bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(),R.drawable.no_album);
            }catch (Exception e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            QuerySongs querySongs = new QuerySongs(songId, albumId, songData, songName, songArtist, songAlbum);
            songList.add(querySongs);

        } while (myCursor.moveToNext());
        myCursor.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: `MediaStore.Audio.Albums.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI` is already a URI where the art is at. Why do you need `Uri.parse("file://"`?

Comment: songList.get(position).getAlbumart() so only this ?

Comment: It's not clear to me what that value is. You need to load a File or a URI, not a string. https://stackoverflow.com/a/23681332/2308683

Comment: can you check my edit, is this what you mean?

Comment: But now it's not loading anything in the imageview

Comment: Nope. `albumArtUri` is not a file itself. It is a directory where your content is stored. You should make `songList.get(position).getAlbumart()` return `Uri` type objects

Comment: So that line i add inside the load for picasso? i'm sorry btw i have really no clue what i'm doing actually.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you're going to need runtime permissions to read files from disk.

Try doing this in the cursor loop

```
Uri albumArt = Uri.parse(albumCursor.getString(album_Art));
```

Add that to your list (after you change it's type from a string)

```
private Uri albumart;
public Uri getAlbumart() { return albumart; }
```

Picasso loads `Uri` objects, and I'm not sure `file://` is resolvable, or appending it to the album art path is correct.

```
public void onBindViewHolder(SongHolder holder, final int position) {

    holder.tvSongTitle.setText(songList.get(position).getTitle());
    holder.tvArtistName.setText(songList.get(position).getArtist());

    Picasso.with(context)
            .load(songList.get(position).getAlbumart()) 
            .error(R.drawable.no_album)
            .into(holder.albumIv);

}
```

Also, lots of code here, but might get something out of it - [Get Album Art With Album Name Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13678391/get-album-art-with-album-name-android)

Comment: And it's ok that my onBindViewHolder is another class right?

Comment: In the RecyclerView

Comment: And what do i pass to my song contstructor? i get Uri cannot be converted to string

Comment: I added all my classes

Comment: Thanks, I guess, but what did you try what I showed?

Comment: This is just something I'm struggling with a long time, and you're the first to actually answer.

Comment: But thanks for the link to the post about it, there is some helpfull stuff there.

Comment: Well, you didn't include any error in the question, but this seems like something that might work closer to what you want. I'm mostly thinking the `file://` part was not correct.

Comment: I tried the things you posted, and the error I get is in the onbindviewholder when I try to get the albumart

Comment: It says it cannot convert a string to a uri

Comment: But yeah I'll check it tomorrow, it's getting late here, but thanks for your response anyway

Comment: There's some specifics about what a URI is mentioned here. https://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/URI.html

Comment: Ok so i tried following the post you linked, and i'm getting an image loaded, but it loads the image when an error occured (no album art), but i'm pretty sure my songs have an albumart.

Answer (score 1):

**Fetch Album Id**

```
public void getSongs() {
    final Uri songUri = MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;

    String selection = MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_MUSIC + "!=0";
    Cursor myCursor = getContentResolver().query(songUri, null, selection, null, null);


    if (myCursor != null && myCursor.moveToFirst()) {
        int id_Column = myCursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Audio.Media._ID);
        int albumId_Column = myCursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Audio.Media.ALBUM_ID);
        int data_Column = myCursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Audio.Media.DATA);
        int title_Column = myCursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Audio.Media.TITLE);
        int artist_Column = myCursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Audio.Media.ARTIST);

        do {

            Long songId = myCursor.getLong(id_Column);
            Long albumId = myCursor.getLong(albumId_Column);
            String songData = myCursor.getString(data_Column);
            String songName = myCursor.getString(title_Column);
            String songArtist = myCursor.getString(artist_Column);

            QuerySongs querySongs = new QuerySongs(songId, albumId, songData, songName, songArtist);
            songList.add(querySongs);

        } while (myCursor.moveToNext());
        myCursor.close();
    }
}
```

**In your Adapter Class**

```
    @Override
     public void onBindViewHolder(SongHolder holder, final int position) {
    //holder.tvIndex.setText(String.format(Locale.US, "%d", position));

    holder.tvSongTitle.setText(songList.get(position).getTitle());
    holder.tvArtistName.setText(songList.get(position).getArtist());


    Uri sArtworkUri = Uri.parse("content://media/external/audio/albumart");
    Uri albumArtUri = ContentUris.withAppendedId(sArtworkUri, songList.get(position).getAlbumid());

    Picasso.with(context)
            .load(albumArtUri)
            .error(R.drawable.no_album)
            .into(holder.albumIv);
}
```